# Check the name of a function passed as an argument in an R function

Tags: r

Suppose I wrote a function that accept another function as an argument:

```
fct1 <- function(FUN) {
    # If FUN is rnorm, then do this.
    # If FUN is rbeta, then do this.
  }
```

How should I check whether FUN is `rnorm`?

I know I can do this to convert the function to a list by `as.list()` and then coerce it to a string by `toString()`:

```
toString(as.list(rnorm))
```

The result is:

```
", 0, 1, .Call(C_rnorm, n, mean, sd)"
```

I can then check the content for `C_rnorm`.

But I think this is not a good solution. I also read somewhere (I cannot remember the source) that coercing a closure to a list and then a string is possible just for backward compatibility, and is not encouraged.

I also thought about `body()`. For example,

```
body(rnorm)
```

The result is:

```
.Call(C_rnorm, n, mean, sd)
```

However, then how can I check if `C_rnorm` is inside the call? I tried to use `as.list()` and then `toString()`:

```
toString(as.list(body(rnorm)))
```

This is the result:

```
".Call, C_rnorm, n, mean, sd"
```

However, is this a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match.call`:

```
fct1 <- function(FUN) {
  called <- match.call()$FUN
  if(called == "rnorm") {
    return("Passed rnorm")
  } else {
    return("Not rnorm")
  }

}

fct1(rnorm)
# [1] "Passed rnorm"
fct1(rlnorm)
# [1] "Not rnorm"
```

Comment: Thanks! It works!

I would like to know how it works. I checked and the `type` of `match.call()$FUN` in the example is `symbol` and the `class` is `name`. I thought (incorrectly) that it would not work because `match.call()$FUN` is not a string.

Is `called` coerced to string in the comparison `called == "rnorm"`?

Comment: @sfcheung Yes, that's pretty much it. Names/symbols are pretty much strings that represents objects. The help page `?name` has some explanations.